# Ng-repeat using $scope from a different state?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have two views, the first one (Search) has a button which when clicked will add an item to $scope.results1 and then take the user to the other view (Results) where the ng-repeat is.

When I click the button and the results page comes up, only "1" is displayed. However, if I call the test function straight away in the controller, I get taken to the Results page and both "1" and "2" are displayed. In both cases, the console log shows that the array results1 contains 2 items.

From what I've read, the solution would be to implement either a factory or a service but I'm fairly new to Ionic/angular so not quite sure how to begin such an implementation, any pointers would be appreciated!

Button in Search view :

```
<button class="button-full" id="find" ng-click="test();">Find</button>
```

SearchController:

```
 $scope.results1=[];
 $scope.results1.push(1);

 $scope.test = function(){
    $scope.results1.push(2);
    console.log("pushed 2");
    console.log($scope.results1);
    $state.go("tab.results");
  };
```

Results view:

```
<ion-content ng-controller="SearchController">
    <body>
      <div id="results">
      <div class="list" id="search-items">
        <div ng-repeat="item in results1">
          {{item}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implememnt a service for holding Results like this

```
var mainApplicationModule = angular.module("yourAppName");

mainApplicationModule.service('ResultService', function(){
    var results = [];
    this.add = function(data){    // to add data to results
        results.push(data);
    }

    this.getResults = function(){    // to get all results
        return(results);
    }
})
```

Inject ResultService into your  SearchController like this,

```
mainApplicationModule.controller('SearchController',['$scope','ResultService','$location', function($scope,ResultService,$location) {

    ResultService.add(1)            // Adds 1 to 'results' array in ResultService
    $scope.test = function() {
        ResultService.add(2);        // Adds 2 to Results array in ResultService
        $location.path("/results")  // replace with path to your results view
    }
    $scope.results1 = ResultService.getResults();  //  will have [1,2]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass data while changing state,

config the state like this:

```
.state('tab.results', {
  url: '/yoururl',
  templateUrl: 'yourtemplate',
  controller: 'yourcontroller',
  params: {
      "results": ""
  }
});
```

then using :

```
$state.go("tab.results",{"results": $scope.results1});
```

in the second controller inject $stateParams and get value:

```
$scope.results = $stateParams.results;
```

Comment: I'm currently using SearchController for both views at the moment, should I make a separate controller for the Results view?

Comment: if you ve the same controller for multiple views then you need a service to share data between them. Or make multiple controllers and change state like my example